# How to CROP a photo which picked from gallery in android?

Tags: android

I am trying to CROP a photo in android, but my temp-photo file always empty(0kb) although I had picked a photo from my gallery.

This is my code :

```
 File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "pictures/softtime");//save path
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                dir.mkdirs();
            }
            currentImageFile = new File(dir, System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg");//path+filename 
            //Create if not exists
            if (!currentImageFile.exists()) {
                try {
                    currentImageFile.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            Intent intentGet = new Intent("android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT");   
            intentGet.setType("image/*");
            intentGet.putExtra("crop",true);
            intentGet.putExtra("scale",true);
            intentGet.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(currentImageFile));
            startActivityForResult(intentGet,CROP);
```

I have run this code at my phone , I found that There is a new file created after I pick a photo ,but the new file is empty (0kb).

what can i do ?

Thank you everyone for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no requirement for `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` activities to support some undocumented `crop` extra. If you want to allow the user to crop an image, use [an image cropping library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45).